# Is this a series or parallel connection?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

I am confused how the capacitors in this circuit are connected. $C_4$, $C_6$ and $C_5$, $C_3$ appear to be parallel, but both $C_4$ and $C_6$ seem to be in series with $C_1$ as do $C_5$ and $C_3$. Am I missing something? I couldn't find explained examples of a circuit with a capacitor in between two parallels like that.

[image: example of circuit]

Comment: More on [parallel vs series](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+parallel+series).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you redraw your diagram as:

[image: Capacitors]

It should be clear which capacitors are in parallel and which are in series.